# Changing font in mlterm

Tags: fonts, unicode, amazon-linux

I am not able to see complex fonts like Devanagari, Arabic, etc correctly in **terminal**-- they do render but circles appear on the screen for Devanagari, Arabic is also garbled. Everything is fine in GUI based editors.

Also,

1. KDE based editors like Konsole not an option
2. I know gnome based editors like `tilix` also solve the problem but I can't use `gnome 3.32` which uses `vte 0.56`-- which solves the circle problem. I have to use `gnome 3.28` and `vte 0.52`.

So my only option seems to be `mlterm` which shows great promise. But after successfully installing it I am not able to see any language text-- everything comes as blank or "squares".

I think `mlterm` is not able to pick the fonts correctly; but I am not able to find a way to change the font that is being used by `mlterm`.

I have read:

1. https://github.com/arakiken/mlterm
2. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/arakiken/mlterm/rel-3_9_0/README
3. https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/how-to-set-font-of-mlterm-769852/

I have also tried the command:

`mlterm-3.9.0/main/./mlterm --km UTF-8 --dyncomb true --deffont=~/.mlterm/vfont --type xft`

and put `ISCII_HINDI=Noto Sans Devanagari` inside the file `~/.mlterm/vfont`

I understand that the `--deffont` argument here: http://mlterm.sourceforge.net/mlterm.1.html needs to be set, but I don't understand what exactly should be inside the file. What should be its syntax?

I want to use Google's Noto fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're telling mlterm to use the `UTF-8` encoding but telling it the font for only the `ISCII_HINDI` encoding.

Instead, try putting one of `DEFAULT=Noto Sans Devanagari`, or `UNICODE=Noto Sans Devanagari`,  in your `.mlterm/*font` files, both of which should work. Equivalently to the first option, you can instead pass `--deffont="Noto Sans Devanagari"` on the command line instead of putting `DEFAULT=Noto Sans Devanagari` into `.mlterm/vfont` file.

Note that the `.mlterm/vfont` file is used only when you have variable width fonts enabled --- otherwise the appropriate file is simply `.mlterm/font`. You can find more about this in the chapter of the man page entitled "`CONFIGURATION`"

If you want to support more languages that aren't covered by the Noto Sans, you can use a list of fonts to try in order after installing the appropriate fonts: e.g. `DEFAULT=Noto Sans Devanagari, Tajawal` uses Tajawal from Google Fonts for Arabic support. Personally, I always add the GNU `Unifont` to the end of any such list, as it has complete (but not necessarily pretty) support for all of Unicode Plane 0.